# Python 2.7 Random Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

In python 2.7 I am trying to create a program that will generate a random number between 100000 and 999999999 and then send it to the users email. So far it creates a random number then sends it to the users email however when the user types in their code it always prints incorrect. How can I fix this?

```
    code = random.randrange(100000, 99999999)

    entry = getpass.getpass('Code: ')
    if entry == code:   
        print 'Welcome!'
    else:
        print 'Incorrect!'
```

Comment: Is `entry` an `int`? Maybe you need `entry = str(getpass.getpass('Code: '))?

Comment: if you send it by email, how should a user enter anything?

Comment: Where's the code for sending it by email? It's between the `code =` line and the `entry =` line, right?

Comment: @EricWilson, `getpass.getpass` return str object.

Comment: Yes the code is in between the code= and the entry= i just discarded it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing int object (which is generated by random.randrange) with str object (which is returned by getpass.getpass); yield always false.

```
>>> 1 == '1'
False
```

Convert `code` to str.

```
>>> str(1) == '1'
True
```

Alternatively You can convert `entry` to int. But then, you should check entry contains only digits or should catch ValueError.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never would have guessed random.randrange would output a string.

Comment: @user2700766, `random.randrange` returns an int, it's `getpass.getpass` that returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that `4 == '4'` is `False`.  You need to compare like data types.  Do

```
if int(entry) == code
```

or

```
if entry == str(code)
```

(also, it's `randrange`, not `randomrange`)

Comment: Thanks and i always accidentally type randomrange thanks for pointing it out.